# How can we prove that ${\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{(1+x)^2}\over{1+x+\sqrt{1+x}}}=1-{x\over 6}$ for small $x$?

Tags: calculus

x is so small that its squares and higher powers are neglegable then prove that

$${\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt[3]{(1+x)^2}\over{1+x+\sqrt{1+x}}}=1-{x\over 6}$$

This might be a problem of Binomial Series

Comment: if $|x^n|\ll1$ for $n>1$ then merely using first-order Taylor polynomials and reduce using elementary algebra techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use: $$\sqrt{x+1}\sim 1+\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$$
And expand $y^{2/3}$ around $y=1$, to get: 
$$y^{2/3}=(x+1)^{2/3}\sim 1 + \frac{2x}{3}+ O(x^2)$$
You'll end up with:
$$\frac{12 + 7 x}{12 + 9 x}$$
Which derivative at $x=0$ is exactly $-1/6$.